# Static column in tableau but rest all columns dynamic with filtering

Tags: tableau-api

I am building a tableau dashboard which has month, region, and account type filter. (Account type can have only two values either New account or old account)

The table in the report should have the following columns:

Month,
Region,
Clicks,
Signups.

Now the issue is clicks are independent of the account type and signups is dependent on the account type.

I am required to create a static clicks columns i.e when a user filters on account type then only signups column numbers change but clicks remain the same.

I have tried multiple ways to create this table but I am unable to reach a solution to this. I also tried creating two workbooks- one with just a clicks column and the other workbook with rest of the columns. After which, I pasted them together side by side in a dashboard. But the formatting looks extremly off and not professional.

Could you please guide me as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a level of detail expression. These are calculated prior to any dimensional filters and therefore will be unaffected by these actions:

Create a calculated field as follows:

```
{ FIXED [Month], [Region]: sum([Clicks]) }
```

This will calculate the sum of the clicks per month and region and ignore any filtering on account.

Let me know if this gives your desired result or if we need to refine further.

Comment: Awesome @GeetikaMital glad to hear. If possible could you take the time to mark it as your accepted answer if you are happy with it. Thanks